# WiX: data in %AppData% are to appear in time

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

WiX.

I write the installer for AutoCAD plugin. It creates menu in the Start -> All Programs -> etc:

[image]

Also, my installer creates the set of `%AppData%` subfolders and copies into them some set of configurable files and `DLL`. These files will be used by my plugin when it will be loaded into AutoCAD. I.e. *these files are to be existing when my plugin is loading into AutoCAD*.

[image]

Now I switch to other Windows user profile. I see my menu, but I don't see my data in the `%AppData%`. If I open my documentation or license file **through one of my shortcuts** of the *Program Menu*, then my data appeares in the `%AppData%` folder at once. Good. *Pay attention that it will happen only if I use shortcut instead of their target files directly.*

Ok, but it is possible what user will load my plugin without opening of my documentation or license file before... At this case the data which are necessary for my plugin working will be absent still... I had a hope what when AutoCAD will load my plugin then its data will appear in the `%AppData%` like this was happening when I used *Program Menu*. But I was mistaken and my data didn't appear in the `%AppData%` at this case.

So, I need either my data will appear in `%AppData%` when user login in Windows, or just before AutoCAD will load my plugin.

Or maybe it is possible in my plugin code through C# to force Windows OS to install the components which are not installed still in the `%AppData%`?

**UPD**

Every user has to have the separate set of files in his `%AppData%` directory because these files are *the custom settings of user interface of my plugin*. Each user has individual need.

How can I solve it?

Comment: %APPDATA% is a per-user folder. If you want to use a per-machine folder you can use %ALLUSERS%

Comment: I read about this property, but I am not sure that I right understand how it works. I need that every user has his own set of files in his `%AppData%` directory. But `%AllUsers%` provides the general files directly for all users instead of each user had the personal files. Am I right?

Comment: You are right. Maybe you should change your app so it does not required per-user files to be installed.

Comment: I thought about it already. I can do it through code of my plugin, but I had a hope that it can be done through MSI installer. It would be more *beautifully* in my opinion.

Comment: I don't agree on that. A installer should handle static files. Settings files and user files should be handled by the app.

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Put the files in the CommonFilesFolder. They are shared binaries for the use of all users on the system, and it looks like there is nothing user specific in those files. Why are they in a user's appdata folder because they don't look like application data. Is there any user-specific data in there?

What you're seeing is Windows Installer behavior - shortcut use checks that the components are installed, and those files are missing for that user so it will install them (for which it will need the original MSI file to be present). This mechanism works with shortcuts, COM components registered with the MSI's Class table, and ProgIds, none of which appear to be invoked when your plugin is loaded.

To force this mechanism to be invoked when the standard Windows Installer entypoints aren't used, call the Win32 (or equivalent) API MsiProvideComponent ()  as soon as your plugin is loaded and before it requires access to the user specific data files, for each missing component. If you put the shared Dlls in some common files folder (instead of per user folders) then you'd do two calls, one for each data file (one file per component being recommended) where each file is the KeyPath to its containing component.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370356(v=vs.85).aspx

It requires the ProductCode, ComponentCode and (internal) feature name of those files. With the default mode parameter, as the docs say, "Provide the component and perform any installation necessary to provide the component." which is what using the shortcut does.

Comment: The specific (for each user) files will be generated by AutoCAD in that folder. Therefore each user shall have the copy of these files. The generated files will contain the user preferences on layout of the menu and toolbars.

My plugin is managed DLL is written on C#. Which COM component I am to create in my plugin's code for installing the absent data in the `%AppData%` directory?

Comment: `CommonFilesFolder` is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\` for x86. This is not the same what I need.

Comment: When you say "what I need", is there an actual technical requirement behind that or a problem to be solved? I don't know how to respond to a comment like that, sorry.

Comment: I don't know how more clearly to explain that the each user need to have the separate set of settings. `CommonFilesFolder` is no good place for it, beacuse *this place is read-only for all users*. So, users can't edit the files of that directory. Sorry what I explain this for you.

Comment: I added UPD section.

Comment: Are the Dlls separate settings too? Or are they just lumped in with the data files for convenience or something?

Comment: `CUIX` files are the custom user interfaces (zipped) i.e. these are the menu files. `DLL` files contains `ICO`, `PNG`, and `BMP` images which are used in the menu files. AutoCAD requires that the `DLL` files were located together with their `CUIX`. Each user can edit the `CUIX` as he needs.